# objects are not valid as a react child when trying to render component based off of AsyncStorage React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, components

I am trying to render a component conditionally based off the value of AsyncStorage, but I am getting the above error. I even tried converting the object to an Array, but that did not work as well. Not sure what else to do.

```js
 const test = async () => {
      const test = await ratingCountCompleted;
      let result = Object.values(test);
      result = result.toString();
      console.log(result);

      if(result > 1) {
        console.log('YUP');
        
        return (
          <InAppRating />
        )
      } else {
        console.log('NOPE')
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently trying to help you out with this over at: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bartik-tri5r?file=/src/App.js), but having a weird interaction where `async` is causing the problem.

EDIT: I think I found the problem. The `test` function is asynchronous and returning a promise as indicated in the error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).`

Solution:

```
const [resultState, setResultState] = useState(null);

const test = async () => {
    const test = await ratingCountCompleted;
    let result = Object.values(test);
    result = result.toString();
    console.log(result);

    if (result > 1) {
        console.log("YUP");

        return <Text>Hey</Text>;
    } else {
        console.log("NOPE");
        return null;
    }
};

// setResultState on load
useEffect(() => {
  test().then((component) => setResultState(component));
}, []);

return <View>{resultState}</View>;
```

We have to use `useState` for our initial component state, which is `null`. Then we populate it with `useEffect`, get the returned promise from `test`, and finally render it.

[A second codesandbox to test it](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-haslett-972s2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Of course, I appreciate the help. I did updated the above to something I tried right after this. I tried converting the array to a string, but it didn't like that still go the error.

Comment: No problem! I think I found the solution, let me know if that works. It looks a little janky, but I believe the useEffect route is always the most optimal in react-native.

Comment: yes this worked, I appreciate it! That was a very helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditionals to render o not elements like in this demo. But you'll need some state to trigger re-rendering. I hope this will help you:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(0);
  const ratingCountCompleted = async () => 2;

  const test = async () => {
    const rating = await ratingCountCompleted();
    setResult(rating);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    test();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(result > 1 && (<Text>Yup</Text>)) || (<Text>Nope</Text>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wozniak-tq71n?file=/src/App.js)